# How to run multiple inserts on multiple tables parallelly using Pyspark

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, hive, parallel-processing

I have insert data from staging to main tables using sql query using pyspark programming. But, the problem is I have inserts to multiple tables. So, in order to achieve parallelism what has to be performed instead of using threading.

```
spark.sql("INSERT INTO Cls.tbl1 (Contract, Name)
SELECT s.Contract, s.Name 
FROM tbl1 AS s LEFT JOIN Cls.tbl1 AS c 
ON s.Contract = c.Contract AND s.Adj = c.Adj
WHERE c.Contract IS NULL")


spark.sql("INSERT INTO Cls.tbl2 (Contract, Name)
SELECT s.Contract, s.Name 
FROM tbl2 AS s LEFT JOIN Cls.tbl2 AS c 
ON s.Contract = c.Contract AND s.Adj = c.Adj
WHERE c.Contract IS NULL")
```

We have to execute multiple insert statements as above and also we want to achieve parallelism when running through spark.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you **cannot** run them in parallel. But you can run two different job, each inserting into one table, you can sort of achieve parallelism with this approach

Comment: But, I don't have an option of inserting on same table, each insert on each table.

Comment: Ah right, you joined using that table as well... I updated my answer a bit, but short answer is still "no, you can't"